# Cannot update ListView builder when data is recieved from Stomp Client Flutter in realtime

Tags: flutter, dart, chat, mobile-application, stomp

I'm working on a Flutter project in which I have to receive a message via using Stomp Client via SockJS. This is working fine, but I want to use the data I'm receiving and add it into the list view builder. I have one screen where are all the chat messages are showing up from an API which is receiving data from DB.

I need help with list view builder to refresh it whenever we receive data from Stomp client.

```
//Stomp_client//
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/api/message_api_service.dart';
import 'package:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/models/message_model.dart';
import 'package:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/screens/chat_screen.dart';
import 'package:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/widgets/messageCard_Sender.dart';
import 'package:stomp_dart_client/stomp.dart';
import 'package:stomp_dart_client/stomp_config.dart';
import 'package:stomp_dart_client/stomp_frame.dart';

String access_token;
String chatroomId;
String chatroomAccKey;
int uid;
Data latestmsg;
void onConnectCallback(StompFrame connectFrame) {
  print("Connected");
  print("/topic/conversations." + chatroomId);
  client.subscribe(
    destination: "/topic/conversations." + chatroomId,
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer $access_token'},
    callback: (StompFrame connectFrame) {
      print("DATA RECIEVED: " + connectFrame.body);
      latestmsg = Data.fromJson(json.decode(connectFrame.body));
      print(latestmsg);
    },
  );

  Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 2), (_) {
    client.send(
      destination: '/app/chat.$chatroomId',
      body: json.encode({'a': 123}),
    );
  });
}

StompClient client = StompClient(
    config: StompConfig.SockJS(
  url:
      'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/sockjs',
  onConnect: onConnectCallback,
  beforeConnect: () async {
    print('waiting to connect...');
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 200));
    print('connecting...');
  },
  heartbeatIncoming: Duration(seconds: 0),
  heartbeatOutgoing: Duration(seconds: 1),
  onWebSocketError: (dynamic error) => print(error.toString()),
  stompConnectHeaders: {'Authorization': 'Bearer $access_token'},
  webSocketConnectHeaders: {'Authorization': 'Bearer $access_token'},
));

void main(String token, String chatroomid, String chatroomAcKey) {
  chatroomAccKey = chatroomAcKey;
  chatroomId = chatroomid;
  print(chatroomid);
  access_token = token;
  client.activate();
}


//API for MESSAGE//
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:XXXXXXXXXX/models/message_model.dart';

class message_api_service {
  String _token;
  String _accessKey;
  String _chatroomID;
  int newSize;
  int oldSize;
  String _url = "http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
  Dio _dio;

  message_api_service(String token, String accessKey, String chatroomID,
      int _newSize, int _oldSize) {
    this._dio = Dio()..options.headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer ${token}";
    this._token = token;
    this._accessKey = accessKey;
    this._chatroomID = chatroomID;
    this.newSize = _newSize;
    this.oldSize = _oldSize;
  }

  Future<Data> fetchallmessages() async {
    try {
      Response response = await _dio.get(_url, queryParameters: {
        'accessKey': "${_accessKey}",
        'chatRoomId': "${_chatroomID}",
        'newSize': "${newSize}",
        'oldSize': " $oldSize"
      });

      message_model mModel = message_model.fromJson(response.data);

      return mModel.data;
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    throw ("error fetching data");
  }
}


//Screen where i m calling stomp client activate//
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    main(widget.token, widget.user.chatRoomId, widget.user.roomAccessKey); //to acctivate stomp client.
 }

//where i was calling message api//
 Expanded(
            child: Container(
                child: FutureBuilder<Data>(
              future: message_api_service(widget.token,
                      widget.user.roomAccessKey, widget.user.chatRoomId, 50, 0)
                  .fetchallmessages(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                      controller: _controller,
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.messages.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return messageCard(
                            snapshot.data.messages[index],
                            snapshot.data.messages[index].sender,
                            widget.ismyEmail,
                            widget.isMyUID);
                      });
                } else {
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
              },
            )),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `class` needs to be `StatefulWidget` and you need to make use of `StreamBuilder` for it automatically update the UI, whenever the changes are detected.

Comment: I am using a StateFullWidget Class in terms to update UI automatically but still not able to to do it. As i m new to working with Stomp and flutter its a bit hard to get. @xpetta